# How would you implement collision detection of circles using only vanilla JavaScript and HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision, detection

I am new to programming, so i might mess something up, but I would think you would make a class to draw circles and/or squares and just keep calling new instances of that class. But I can't figure out how to go about doing that.

Comment: Creating circles using a class is the way if you want to use OOP. There are other paradigms to use as well. Collision detection of circles is simple, just check, that the distance of the centres of the circles is not equal or smaller than the sum of the radii of the circles.

Answer (score 1):

A circle-circle collision detection algorithm is surely the easiest to implement due to the equal distance from a circles' center to any point on it's outside.

For this we can make use of the **Pythagorean theorem**, which says that in a right triangle the sum of the area of squares put on the triangle's two shorter sides equals the area of a square put on the longest side. If we know it's area - and the fact that it's a square - we know that we can simply calculate the square root to get it's side length.

While this surely sounds a little abstract, it gets way more obvious if you take a look at the following picture:

[image]

Here you see two circles - Circle A & Circle B - and a right angle triangle put between those, so the longest side (red) touches the circles' center points. You notice that the red side **is** the distance between the circles. If we calculate the red side and check if it's shorter than the sum of the radius of Circle A and Circle B we know they collide!

So according to the Pythagorean theorem, we need to put a square on the blue and the green side and take the square root of the summed-up area.

To put a 'virtual' square on e.g. the blue side, we need to know it's actual length and to do this we simply subtract Circle A's vertical position from Circle B's - or vice versa. e.g

```
let sideA = circleB.y - circleA.y;
```

Depending on the actual position this might result in a negative number, so we wrap the calculation in a call to `Math.abs()` which returns the absolute positive value.

```
let sideA = Math.abs(circleB.y - circleA.y);
```

Now do the same for the green side using the circles' horizontal position:

```
let sideB = Math.abs(circleB.x - circleA.x);
```

Calculate the area, sum it and take the square root:

```
let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideA, 2) + Math.pow(sideB, 2));
```

That's it!

Here's an actual example in action:

```js
class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, radius, name) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let circleA = new Circle(50, 50, 35, 'Circle A');
let circleB = new Circle(200, 110, 35, 'Circle B');
let circleC = new Circle(110, 50, 35, 'Circle C');

let circles = [circleA, circleB, circleC];

ctx.textAlign = 'center';
for (let a = 0; a < circles.length; a++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circles[a].x, circles[a].y, circles[a].radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillText(circles[a].name, circles[a].x, circles[a].y);
}

function checkCollision(circle1, circle2) {
  let sideA = Math.abs(circle1.y - circle2.y);
  let sideB = Math.abs(circle1.x - circle2.x);
  let distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sideA, 2) + Math.pow(sideB, 2));

  return distance <= circle1.radius + circle2.radius;
}

let result = document.getElementById('result');
result.innerText = 'Circle A touches Circle B: ' + checkCollision(circleA, circleB)
result.innerText += '\nCircle A touches Circle C: ' + checkCollision(circleA, circleC)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas><br>
<span id="result"></span>
```